# Run bash script in an existing terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to code a watchdog function for a bash script that checks every second ,for a maximum of 90 seconds, if a flag file generated by a bash script that is running in another terminal window exists. If after 90 seconds the flag file still does not exist, the watchdog kills the bash script running in another terminal by running `kill -9 TERMINALPD`. Once killed (the kill -9 command doesn't actually kill the terminal window, it just kills the script as if someone pressed Ctrl+z), is there a way to make it start again? Is there a way to automatically emulating someone typing into that terminal `./script`?

Comment: Your description is a bit vague - can you provide a step-by-step example to clarify your intention?

Comment: You would need to determine the *pts* the second script was run on (see [Difference between pts and tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21280/difference-between-pts-and-tty)) and then restart on that pts. I don't have a silver-bullet for you.

Comment: I tried using xterm, but is there a way to close the window after exiting the script? Otherwise it would keep creating new xterm windows...

Comment: You're desribing a classic use case for the [Linux screen tool](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)